# Linear regression when response values are high-dimensional

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to do linear regression with some data I just got, but I just do not know how to start. The problem to me is that the response (y) values are multi-dimensional like a vector.

For example:

```
sample 1, y <- c(3,7,10,36,23), while x1 <- 3, x2 <- 2, x3 <- 12, ....
sample 2, y <- c(4,5,13,21,9), while x1 <- 4, x2 <- 5, x3 <- 7, ....
....
```

Comment: It's not particularly clear to me what you are trying to do. Simultaneous linear regression? Independent linear regression (as @Pash101 does below)? Something else? Can you please clarify your problem and expected output?

Comment: The y is the value we got from images which is multi-dimensional for each sample. X is some genomic data for the samples. We are trying to see if there is any correlation between sample image features and sample's genomic data. The samples are tumors from patients.  Because of the high-dimension of samples genomic data ( ~ 20K predicators), at first we planed to do a partial least square regression before we saw the format of image data which has about 10 features. Thanks!

Comment: So you have a `p >> n` problem and you need to do variable selection. It's still not clear to me what you're trying to do. I think you'll get more answers if you rephrase your question, clarify your thoughts, and describe what you've already done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easily in R.

```
df <- data.frame(c(3,4),c(7,5),c(10,13),c(36,21),c(23,9),c(3,4),c(2,5),c(12,7))
colnames(df) <- c("y1","y2","y3","y4","y5","x1","x2","x3")
lmod1 <- lm(cbind(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5)~x1+x2+x3,data=df)

#or you can combine these into a matrix
y <- matrix(c(df$y1,df$y2,df$y3,df$y4,df$y5),ncol=5)
x <- matrix(c(df$x1,df$x2,df$x3),ncol=3)
lmod2 <- lm(y~x)
```

Note - in this example code the estimates for x2/x3 will fail, this is just because there are so few observations (but it should work for the real data set).

edit - I should probably also add that this approach will fit  separate univariate models, which assumes independence between y1,y2,y3 etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Because of the high-dimension of samples genomic data ( ~ 20K predicators), is it possible to mod this to do a PLS? Thanks!